# How to rewrite java.sql.Array Descriptor and java.sql.ARRAY in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, spring-boot

Previously I used this code to call an Oracle stored procedure:

```java
ArrayDescriptor arrydes = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("Data TYPE", Connection);
ARRAY arryId = new ARRAY(arrydes, Connection, String[]);
```

But now migrating to Spring boot, we don't need to call connection object and ArrayDescriptor is deprecated. So how can we rewrite this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class).createOracleArray("Data TYPE", String[])
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko what explanation besides this does what OP wants could I possibly give? OP wants to create and Oracle array and this creates an Oracle array.

Comment: anything that can point out the flaw in OP's code. Anyway, code-only answers are considered low-quality

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko ArrayTypeDescriptor is deprecated, as OP says, #createOracleArray is the recommended way to do it, as per official Oracle documentation. There is not more to say.

Comment: @user2121148 can you post the rest of the code and the full stack trace?

Comment: Thanq Philippe Marschall